# Parse.com Project Hosting

Tags: parse-platform, web-hosting, errno, ioerror

I am new to Parse.com and trying to create a Project Directory using "Parse new". Whenever I do I get the following.

Anyone know what Errno 22 is and why it is thrown?

Thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\main", line 719, in main
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\main", line 438, in handle_add
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\config_handler", line 225, in add_
alias
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\mwalker\\Gerhart
TS\\config\\global.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is in your escaping, if the compiler outputs `c:\\` the string is `s = "c:\\\\\\\\";`

Other problem could be premission (try to run as admin), and please check that 'C:\Users\mwalker\Gerhart
TS\config\' exists.